# Dropbox api .net

Tags: android, ios, .net, dropbox-api

we have a website in .net, now we want to implement **dropbox api for .net** so clients can upload/download files on our dropbox account. Our question is can they download files this way on their andoroid and iOS devices?

They can thru web browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Dropbox offers an API that can be used from any platform that can make HTTPS calls. You can find everything you need here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers

We recommend using one of the official SDKs, but if you can't, you can also use the endpoints directly. For example, to download a file:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download